# How to embed a plotly chart in an iframe when plotly_min.js is linked in the parent frame

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I have an HTML document with multiple iframes, each of which contains a plotly chart. In a simplified version, `parent_document.html` looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.20.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="child_document.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

and `child_document.html` looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
<script>
    TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');
    Plotly.newPlot( TESTER, [{
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16] }], {
    margin: { t: 0 } } );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This can't work as it stands because Plotly is not defined in `child_document.html`. Linking the Plotly library in `child_document.html` does of course fix it but won't work for the real application as we have multiple iframes updating in response to user selections; reloading the whole of plotly_min every time makes the application very sluggish.

I tried replacing the call to `Plotly` in `child_document.html` with various versions of `window.parent.Plotly` or `window.top.Plotly` but with no luck. I also tried putting the following immediately before the chart:

```
<script>
     Plotly = window.top.Plotly;
</script>
```

I tried the same for PLOTLYENV as well.

What's the right way to reference plotly from within a frame?